# Running a single validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I'm sending friends invitations and I want to validate email address using `User.validates_format_of :email`, except that User.email has a couple of other validations which I'm not really interested in.

So is there a way to run a single validation on a model or check if that specific validation has passed (without doing 

`user.errors.include?(validation_message)`

)?

Answer (score 10):

You can check the gem [grouped_validations](https://github.com/adzap/grouped_validations)

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validation_group :name do
    validates_presence_of :first_name
    validates_presence_of :last_name
  end
  validates_presence_of :sex
end
```

Then you can do this in your controller

```
p = Person.new
p.group_valid?(:name) # => false
p.first_name = 'John'
p.last_name = 'Smith'
p.group_valid?(:name) # => true
```

Comment: Great, thanks for this gem link. This functionality should be in Rails already IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Create a method like this in your model and use it for partial validation

```
def has_valid_name?
  valid? || (errors[:first_name].empty? && errors[:last_name].empty?)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a specific error has been added:

```
user.errors.added? :name, :blank
```